# Delegate not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I feel frustrated with this problem, I my delegate doesn't work, Here's the code snippet below. I'm just using xib in this application.

//classA.h file
    **ClassA.h**

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA : UIViewController< ClassBDelegate >

//classA.m file
**ClassA.m**

-(void)didSuccessPreview:(ClassB *)controller andLog:(NSString *)log{
    NSLog(@"%@", log);
}

//classB.h file
**ClassB.h**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ClassB;

@protocol ClassBDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didSuccessPreview:(ClassB *)controller andLog:(NSString *)log;

@end

@interface ClassB : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id< ClassBDelegate >delegate;

//classB.m file
**ClassB.m**

I add this code below inside view did load

[self.delegate didSuccessPreview:self andLog:@"zz"];
```

I have other delegate inside my application same as the code above, but it works but this one is not, I don't know why. Inside my classA I have a button then when i click it it goes to classB, then when it goes to viewdidload in ClassB, the delegate doesn't fired.

Comment: When are you setting the delegate? (i.e., `self.delegate = someObject`)

Comment: Do i need to create an object for it? I also added in my classA.m ClassB *test = [ClassB new] and test.delegate = self, but not working also..

Comment: You need to create an instance of `ClassA` (the one that adopts the protocol) and assign it to the `delegate` property of the `ClassB` object. If `self.delegate` in your code above is `nil` (zero), the method won't be executed!

Comment: If you are using ARC, then it is `self.delgate = [ClassA new];` or equivalently `self.delgate = [[ClassA alloc] init];` (unless `ClassA` requires some more specific intializer instead of `init`).

Comment: y classA? my delegate is setup on classB... can you edit my code and show me??

Comment: Because the delegate is of type ClassA.

Comment: I mean, `ClassA` is the one that conforms to the protocol `ClassBDelegate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you assign the delegate, your code might need to look like this:

```
ClassB viewController = [ClassB new];
ClassA delegateStrongRef = [ClassA new]

viewController.delegate = delegateStrongRef; // <-- you are missing this now;
// Fixed: the ClassA object must be referenced strongly somewhere else
// besides the (weak)delegate property, otherwise it will be deallocated.
```

(The code above is the part where you create the instance of `ClassB`, the view controller. It might be inside the AppDelegate, another viewController's implementation, anything - depending on how your app is structured).

Then, in the view controller's `-viewDidload` method, you can have the delegate execute a method like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.delegate didSuccessPreview:self andLog:@"zz"];
}
```

so, at some point after instantiating your view controller, you need to assign an object of type `ClassA` (the class that adopts the delegate protocol) to its `delegate` property, otherwise it will be `nil` and any messages sent to it will be ignored (no method executed).
Properties and instance variables of object type are not allocated automatically, but initialized to nil (`int`s, `float`s etc, are initialized to 0, 0.0f, etc.)

EDIT: If you are assigning the delegate from `ClassA`'s code, then it might look like this:

**ClassA.m:**

```
- (void) someMethodOfClassA
{
    ClassB viewController = [ClassB new];
    viewController.delegate = self;

    // e.g., Do something with the view controller...
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Since the `delegate` property is defined as a `weak` reference, before calling any method of the delegate make sure it has not been deallocated and its reference set back to `nil` (use `NSLog` or set a breakpoint).